# Single Sign-On for Yii and Magento on same server

Tags: php, magento, single-sign-on

I have two separate php site developed using **yii** and **Magento**, we are keeping user data sync using some API to maintain same user name and password for these two sites.

how we would develop functionality, where in user can log in into any one of the application and looded in another application automatically, like google services if we log in into gmail, it shows logged in into google+ and other google services.

I read about **Single Sign On**, but know idea about how it exactly work. please guide how we can build single sign On on same server.

Answer (score 5):

```
$array['data'][] = $otherObject;
```

Comment: am using same but its not working.

Comment: Is `$arr` even an array (`$arr = array()`)? Seems, that you increase your error settings on your development system

Answer (score 0):

```
array_push( $array['data'], new StdClass() );
```

…does not overwrite anything, but append to the end of the array and is similar to using:

```
$array['data'][] = new StdClass();
```

If something gets overwritten, there must be an error elsewhere.

BTW: there is a PHP-class [`SplObjectStorage`](http://php.net/class.splobjectstorage.php) which is meant to store objects and may be used as in:

```
$array['data'] = new SplObjectStorage();
$array['data']->attach( new StdClass() );
```